# Multi column css http://jsfiddle.net/efLfL/

Tags: css

I want to create css that can acomplish my need.

If screen size is 320px then (left margin 10px) - 300 fixed column  - (right margin 10)

If screen size is 810px then (left margin 10px) - 480 new column - (margin 10) - fixed column 300 + (margin 10)

If screen size is 940px  then 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - fiexed column 300 - 10

If screen size is 990px then 10 - new column 325 - 10 - new coumn 325 - 10 - fixed column 300 - 10

If screen size is 1250px then 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10

If screen size is 3840px then 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10 - new column 300 - 10

Could you please help me to get this done?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: please show us your HTML, css, and scripting code, and maybe a jsfiddle, so we can help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/efLfL/

Comment: If space is not available then left column should be at top and fixed column should be at bottom.  http://jsfiddle.net/efLfL/

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using MEdia Queries

```
 @media (max-width:your width)
{

   //your width specific CSS Here
}
```